# Python fpdf add dashed line for Index page

Tags: python, fpdf

I want to create an Index page.

How can I add a dashed line between cells (name and page) that I don't know the width of?

There is the dashed line method, but to use it I need to specify the width and place it between two cells where the first one I don't know the size...

[image]

Comment: Can you try finding the string width with `get_string_width()`? https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/get_string_width/index.html

Comment: This is good news! I'll post the solution as soon as I find it

Answer (score 0):

This was my partial solution.

`self.__index` is a `Dict<string, int>`

```
for item in self.__index.items():
    if item[0] and not item[0].isspace() and item[0] != "Index":
        # get with of title
        widthl = self.get_string_width(str(item[0])) + 3
        # get width of page number
        widthr = self.get_string_width(str(item[1])) + 3

        # not sure why I need to add + 3 at get_string_width,
        # but that makes the width correct in all cases I tested 

        # adds cell with title
        self.cell(widthl,
                  5,
                  txt=str(item[0]),
                  border=0)

        # adds dashed line
        self.dashed_line(self.x - 1,
                         self.y + 4,
                         self.w - self.r_margin - widthr,
                         self.y + 4)

        # adds page number (width 100% text aligned right)
        self.cell(0,
                  5,
                  txt=str(item[1]),
                  border=0,
                  align="R")

        # Go to next line
        self.ln()
```

Result:
[image]

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465361/index-page-on-fpdf-how-to-write-to-an-existing-page/74603159#answer-74603159) to learn how I added the index at the correct location