# Index page on FPDF. How to write to an existing page?

Tags: python, fpdf

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74435849/python-fpdf-add-dashed-line-for-index-page).

I need to add an index page to the PDF and it needs to be placed after the main page.
So, the index should be on page 2 onwards.

I can add a blank page as a placeholder so that the others get the correct page number, then at the end when all pages are created I need to go back to the blank page and write the index (or create at the end of the document and replace the existing blank one).

<strike>If the index is more than one page (second problem) all the pages will need to update the index.</strike>
I can easily count the number of titles and estimate the amount of pages needed for the index.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's easier than I thought, I'll leave it here just in case someone stumbles upon the same issue.

**1 step:** calculate the number of pages the index will need and add them as blank pages, not required, but will make the page numbers correct already

**2 step:** before finalizing the document, use `self.page = 2` to start adding content to page 2, this will use the blank pages used in the previous step